# Reactive Extensions: Getting the "aperture" of a binary number

Tags: c#, algorithm, system.reactive, reactive-programming

A friend has proposed this challenge. Just for training, I tried to solve it using Reactive Extensions but I had no luck. It's not strange, since I'm still a newbie with Rx.

This is the problem:

> An aperture within a positive integer N is any maximal sequence of
>   consecutive zeros in its binary representation that is surrounded by
>   ones at both ends.
>
> For example, number 9 has binary representation 1001 and contains an
>   aperture of length 2. The number 529 has binary representation
>   1000010001 and contains two apertures: one of length 4 and one of
>   length 3. The number 20 has binary representation 10100 and contains
>   one aperture of length 1. The number 15 has binary representation 1111
>   and has no apertures. Write a function: class Aperture { public int
>   aperture(int N); } that, given a positive integer N, returns the
>   length of its longest aperture. The function should return 0 if N
>   doesn't contain an aperture. 　 Assume that: N is an integer within the
>   range [1..2,147,483,647] Complexity: Algorithmic time complexity is
>   O(log(N));
>
> Algorithmic space complexity is O(1) (worst case – not counting input
>   args)

To simplify, I've tried to apply it to strings like "1000010001", not
binary representations.

Anyways, I don't mind the complexities part, just I would like to know an "elegant" way to do it.

Comment: Sounds like a fun homework assignment from your "friend". I'm going to give it a try in Haskell tomorrow since I'm learning it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, there's not a lot of point solving this in RX since the answer is only deduced by examining the entire number - and for a whole bunch of other reasons it's hugely inefficient...

...but for your entertainment :), here's a very silly RX way *(do not do this at home!)*:

```
public int Aperture(int input)
{
    var cs = Convert.ToString(input,2).ToCharArray().ToObservable();     

    return cs.Publish(ps => ps.Buffer(() => ps.Where(c => c == '1')))
    .Where(x => x.LastOrDefault() == '1')
    .Select(x => x.Count - 1).StartWith(0)
    .Max().Wait();
}

Aperture(9)   = 2
Aperture(529) = 4
Aperture(20)  = 1
Aperture(15)  = 0
```

#### Here's another way!

I'm not sure why I'm doing this :) but here's another way, that's a bit punchier. I'm basically using a 2-tuple as an accumulator. I store a running count of 0's on one side. If I see a 1 I copy the count to the result slot *if it's higher than what's there*, and reset the count. The result slot contains the aperture at the end.

```
public int Aperture(int input)
{    
    var cs = Convert.ToString(input,2).ToCharArray().ToObservable();

    return cs.Aggregate(
        Tuple.Create(0,0), (acc, c) => c == '0'
            ? Tuple.Create(acc.Item1 + 1, acc.Item2)
            : Tuple.Create(0, Math.Max(acc.Item1, acc.Item2)
        )).Wait().Item2;
}
```

Also, just remove the `ToCharArray().ToObservable()` and the `Wait()` from the above and you have an `IEnumerable<T>` version!

Comment: Impressive. Just one more question: What does the final "Wait()" do?

Comment: A bit like `Task.Result`, it waits for the observable stream to finish and returns the last element.

Comment: @SuperJMN Couldn't help myself, I added another way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to use Rx here. My solution illustrates a classic approach:

```
private static int Aperture(int n)
{
    int max = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int lastIndex = int.MaxValue;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        int bit;
        n = Math.DivRem(n, 2, out bit);
        if (bit != 0)
        {
            int length = index - lastIndex - 1;
            if (length > max)
                max = length;
            lastIndex = index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Test results:

```
Aperture(9)   = 2
Aperture(529) = 4
Aperture(20)  = 1
Aperture(15)  = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that using Rx for this is silly. Using LINQ to solve the problem is equally silly, but since it is Rx's big brother, you might as well.

*As with James World's answer, this is for entertainment purposes only.*

```
public int Aperture(int input)
{
    var binaryString = Convert.ToString(input, 2);

    // The accumulator is an integer array maintaining
    // the count of '0's since the last seen '1'.
    // Whenever a '1' is encountered, a new count
    // of zero is added at the end of the array.
    // Whenever a '0' is encountered, the last
    // count is incremented by one.
    var segments = binaryString.Aggregate(
        new [] { 0 },
        (acc, c) =>
            c == '0'
            ? acc
                .Take(acc.Length - 1)
                .Concat(new [] { acc[acc.Length - 1] + 1 })
                .ToArray()
            : acc
                .Concat(new [] { 0 })
                .ToArray()
    );

    return segments
        // If last segment count is non-zero, it was not
        // closed with a '1' and we want to exclude it.
        .Take(segments.Length - 1)
        .Max();
}

[TestMethod]
public void ApertureTest()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(2, Aperture(9));   // 1001,       Segments: 0, 2, 0
    Assert.AreEqual(4, Aperture(529)); // 1000010001, Segments: 0, 4, 3, 0
    Assert.AreEqual(1, Aperture(20));  // 10100,      Segments: 0, 1, 2
    Assert.AreEqual(0, Aperture(15));  // 1111,       Segments: 0, 0, 0, 0
}
```

Now I feel dirty.